# should I use the same port for tcp-based server-client-connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, process, port

I am trying to understand the topic of networking by writing java-programs (learning by doing). I wrote a client and a server in java using java.net.Socket. The client is a class and the server is a class. Then I instantiated the two classes in one Main-class. The java-Application run on my computer. When I assign the same port to the client and the server, then I get no error (ex: port 80). But when I assign different ports (ex: port 80 to server and port 9090 to client) then I get an error. Should I use the same port for tcp-connection?
I want to understand why  I get an error.
here is my whole code put in one java-package:

```
package client_server;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import  java.net.*;
import java.util.Date;


public class Server {
    ServerSocket server;
    Server(){
       System.out.println("server starts");
        try{
        //server runs on port 9090
         server=new ServerSocket(9090);
        }catch(IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

void listen(){
    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("server is listining");
        socket=server.accept();
        PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        out.println(new Date().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

}

```
package client_server;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;
public class Client {
    Socket clientSocket;
    Client(){
        System.out.println("Client starts");
        final String server_ip_adress="127.0.0.1";
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(server_ip_adress,80);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

void connectToServer(){
    try{
        System.out.println("client connects to server");
        InputStream clientInput=clientSocket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientInput));
        String answer = input.readLine();
        System.out.println(answer);

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

}

```
package client_server;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Server server = new Server();
        Client client = new Client();
        server.listen();
        client. connectToServer();
   }
}
```

Theoretically it should work, because each process (server-process and client process) will be assigned a port and it does not matter if the interprocess-communication occurs on different ports.

But in my case  I have one process. So when I assign  different ports it throw an error. Is my analysis correct?
I getthis error:  Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Comment: You may want to read up on socket basics. You also may want to show relevant code and the actual exception messages. Basically a server _listens_ on a port, a client _connects_ to that same port.

Comment: You can't use the same port on the same IP anyway which makes your statement about that hard to believe. Without code we cannot answer. Closing for now.

Comment: I have basics (theoretical background) but I never wrote programs on that topics. So I am doing it now::)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server listens at port 9090, so the client has to connect to port 9090. But it isn't the case that the client is 'assigned' port 9090. Actually when you run `netstat` after connecting the client, you will see that the client is using another port, allocated by the system.

NB by the time you print 'client connects to server' the client is already connected, when `new Socket(...)` returns.